# The Tkinter button is disappearing

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter

app = tkinter.Tk()
app.geometry("1080x2400")

title = tkinter.Label(
    app, text="contador de sets y descansos", font=("Arial", 30))
title.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH)

design = tkinter.Label(app, bg="white")
design.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)


def series():
    label = tkinter.Label(sets, text="completed a set")
    label.pack()


sets = tkinter.Button(design, text="sets", padx=40,
                      pady=20, font=("Arial", 20), command=series)
sets.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)


def descanso():
    label = tkinter.Label(rest, text="completed rest")
    label.pack()


rest = tkinter.Button(design, text="rest", padx=40,
                      pady=20, font=("Arial", 20), command=descanso)
rest.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT,)


app.mainloop()
```

I tried to make a button that displays a message on the GUI, but when I press it, the button disappears, and what I want is the button to display the message and stay there.

Comment: It is extremely strange to be creating widgets as a child of a Label or Button - the usual parents are windows or Frames.

Comment: WHERE do you want the message to be displayed?  What you have done is make the labels be children of the buttons, which means the must display INSIDE the buttons.

Comment: @TimRoberts I want it to appear below the button or in a separate text box

Comment: Ae you expecting this message to display on a `label` widget? It sounds like you want the buttons to change/display on a widget you have not created yet? Are you looking for a new `label` to display these messages?

Answer (score 1):

Use `app` for all in line 17, 21, 27 and 31. You had this `Button(design,`. Should be `Button(app,`

Here is code:

```
import tkinter

app = tkinter.Tk()
app.geometry("1080x2400")

title = tkinter.Label(
    app, text="contador de sets y descansos", font=("Arial", 30))
title.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH)

design = tkinter.Label(app, bg="white")
design.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)


def series():
    label = tkinter.Label(app, text="completed a set")
    label.pack()


sets = tkinter.Button(app, text="sets", padx=40,
                      pady=20, font=("Arial", 20), command=series)
sets.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)


def descanso():
    label = tkinter.Label(app, text="completed rest")
    label.pack()


rest = tkinter.Button(app, text="rest", padx=40,
                      pady=20, font=("Arial", 20), command=descanso)
rest.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT,)


app.mainloop()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: yes, this is nice, thank you toyota Supra

Comment: Glad I help.  It is my pleasure to help.